# A generic error occurred in GDI+ using C#

Tags: c#, android, base64

I am sending `base64String` from Android to `C# webservice` and then converting that `base64String` to Image.
Now, issue is that It is giving error A generic error occurred in GDI+. But I am confused here because `It is working fine on local server and getting error only on Hosting Server`. I have also checked `base64String` on some `Online tools` for image verification and My string is perfect.
**My Code is as below :**

```
public System.Drawing.Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
    {
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
        {
            ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);
            return image;
        }
    }
System.Drawing.Image convertedImage = Base64ToImage(Photo);
                    photoname = FirstName.Trim().Replace(" ", "-") + "__" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyy_HH-mm-ss");
                    convertedImage.Save(Server.MapPath("~\\images\\ProfilePhotos\\" + photoname + ".jpg"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

**Android Code:**

```
final int maxSize = 250;
                int outWidth;
                int outHeight;
                int inWidth = selectedImage.getWidth();
                int inHeight = selectedImage.getHeight();
                if (inWidth > inHeight) {
                    outWidth = maxSize;
                    outHeight = (inHeight * maxSize) / inWidth;
                } else {
                    outHeight = maxSize;
                    outWidth = (inWidth * maxSize) / inHeight;
                }

                Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(selectedImage,
                        outWidth, outHeight, false);

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
                byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

                strBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're creating the `MemoryStream` object inside a `using` block, which means it will be collected by the GC when code leaves the `using` block, thus making the `Image` object orphan. Simply remove the `using` block and use a simple variable declaration there.

```
var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length));
ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);
return image;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make Sure That your destination folder have read/write permission (check it twice!).
2. Make Sure you have free space on your destination drive or folder. 4. Most of the times we cant user Memory Streamers On Shared Servers, So we should be make sure that provider allow us to use it.

   // Once finished with the bitmap objects, we deallocate them.
       originalBMP.Dispose();

   ```
   bannerBMP.Dispose();
   oGraphics.Dispose();
   ```

Comment: I have given Full Control to destination folder.

Comment: Yes, Memory Streamers permission can be issued here because It is working fine on our another vps servers and I am running this on Shared Server.

Comment: if u running shared server log in to cpanel and gives permission to read write and it should be fine

Comment: Do you think that I am getting this issue just because of File Permission ? I have given Full Permission to images folder, is it ok ?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling ms.Write while the constructor already did that for you.

```
    public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
    {
        var imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
        {
            var image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
            return image;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ohk, removed it. But it is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

> A generic error occurred in GDI+

can also occur is the path given to **Image.Save** is incorrect.

What `Server.MapPath("~\\images\\ProfilePhotos\\" + photoname + ".jpg")` is returning?

Answer (score 0):

Check a path, where you going to save an image. I'd had this issue too. The problem, when you get an exception "A generic error occurred in GDI+", is you don't see System.IO's exception. Try this code:

```
string savePath = Server.MapPath("~\\images\\ProfilePhotos\\");
if (!Directory.Exists(savePath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(savePath);
}
convertedImage.Save(savePath + photoname + ".jpg"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Isn't `Check [the path] where you going to save an image` included in [Anant Dabhi's 2014 `Make Sure That your destination folder have read/write permission…`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23026252)?